# Tag request: ruby-devkit (or rubydevkit)

Tags: feature-request, tags, retag-request

Most of the [devkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devkit)'s refer to the [RubyInstaller devkit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) and considering [tcldevkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcldevkit) exists and there certainly more ruby-devkit questions, should there be a [ruby-devkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-devkit) tag, and [devkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devkit) should be rebranded for a more general bucket of devkits?

Comment: I'd go for [tag:ruby-devkit]. It's easier on eyes.